# how to target correct link with jquery confirm library

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, target

I am using [this](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/) library to confirm a users actions when a link is clicked.  The following code works well when only one link exists, but I have hundreds of links on my page that need to be able to use this confirm dialogue.

```
$('.confirm').confirm({
            text: "By clicking yes you are confirming that you want to remove this category and ALL PRODUCTS that are associated with it.  Do you wish to continue?"
            });
```

The dialogue functions just fine, but when I confirm it sends me to the wrong link.  I have been able to establish that it is simply finding the first instance of .confirm in the DOM and activating that link. While it makes sense to me that it would function like that, I need to know how to target the correct link.  I've thought about dynamically generating id's for all the links but that seems like a very poor way to solve this problem.  I am also aware that there are any number of different methods of solving this problem without using this library but I am not interested in them because this particular library fits my theme.

Comment: The jquery plugin should bind to every seperate element so your code should work. Are you sure that the links are correct?

Comment: Yes I'm 100% sure the links are correct because I have inspected them and if this script is removed they function correctly without confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure way this plugin is not functioning correctly but you could try this:

```
$('.confirm').each(function() {
   $(this).confirm({
            text: "By clicking yes you are confirming that you want to remove this category and ALL PRODUCTS that are associated with it.  Do you wish to continue?"
            });
});
```

Comment: This worked.  Ironically I had tried something like this earlier, but must have gotten the syntax wrong.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well i was a bit confused because every jquery plugin has something like this implemented in it, but i'm glad that i could help